# Not able to point Apache beam to GCP big query emulator for integration testing purpose?

Tags: python, testing, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, apache-beam

I am trying to point Apache beam code to gcp bq emulator https://github.com/goccy/bigquery-emulator . pLease suggest a way to run beam integration test

```
    data_load_result = records | "WriteDataToBQ" >> WriteToBigQuery(
        table=<table_id>,
        dataset=<dataset_id>,
        project=<project>,
        create_disposition=BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
        write_disposition=BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

you should consider using a `DataflowRunner` on a development project/dataset to do tests instead of a emulated which is not supported by Google cloud. Typically, you should be provisioned with development and test projects and datasets in google cloud to carry out such testing scenarios.

see documentation links below

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#run-on-dataflow

https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/dataflow/

Hope this helped.